# Problem with iOS devices and BLE stack version 02.12

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, silicon

I'm trying to connect two iOS devices (iPhone 7, v13.2 and iPhone 5S v12.4.3) with a BLE chip with stack 02.12 of silicon Labs, but it does not work.

With previous version of stack (02.04) every device can correctly connect to. I can't figure out which is the problem.
I tried using BlueGecko, BLEScanner and LightBlue apps but no one works.

With Android devices I have no problems.

Comment: Please provide code and a more specific problem description than just "it not works". It's unlikely somebody can help you with so little information.

Comment: I've figured out the problem: with new version of SDK there's no more stack however only an appLoader. It can establish connection without any pairing key, so if you try to reconnect after an OTA operation, the two devices can't communicate and a disconnect function will be called